# PHP MySQLi calling 3 different procedures error

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I want to call 3 different procedures in one connection
but i still get error
**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object**

but calling one at a time works for every call.

Code bellow::

```
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
...
$sql1 = "CALL `something`.`proc_something1`(4,10);";         
$sql2 = "CALL `something`.`proc_something2`(4,10);";         
$sql3 = "CALL `something`.`proc_something3`(4,10);";         

$results1 = $db->query($sql1);                              
while($row1 = $results1->fetch_object()){                   
    print_r($row1);                                          
    echo '<br/>';                                            
}                                                           

$results2 = $db->query($sql2);                              
while($row2 = $results2->fetch_object()){                   
    print_r($row2);                                          
    echo '<br/>';                                            
}                                                           

$results3 = $db->query($sql3);                              
while($row3 = $results3->fetch_object()){                   
    print_r($row3);                                          
    echo '<br/>';                                            
}
```

is there an easy way to correct code above?

Comment: Obviously, `$db->query($sql1)` fails. Have you tried executing your batch using phpmyadmin for example?

Comment: try call your storeprocedure in database, because your query fail.

Comment: connecting to database works and first procedure give results on screen but there is problem with second and third call, each call separately works perfectly

Comment: Try adding "$db->close()" after each while loop.

Comment: I found solution maybe not the best one but still  I added
after every `while`

    $results1->close();
    $db->next_result();
 
thanks for help:)